# jQuery show/hide bar depending on css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic number of images with a delete button. the first time i click a delete button the image is selected and a bar at the top appears. if i click the same button again, the image is unselected and the top bar should disappear again. the same should happen with multiple selections /removals of selection.

I tried to achieve this by adding a class on click (selected) and removing it when clicked again.

I then count the the length of the class (how many exist) and if equals 0, the top bar should disappear again.

the console.log shows me that it always counts 0.

what am i missing?

```js
var bar = $('#bar');
var deleteBtn = $('.delete');
var selected = $('.selected');
var selection = 0;



deleteBtn.click(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  }

  var selection = selected.length;

  if (bar.hasClass("hide")) {
    bar.addClass("show");
  } else {
    if (selection === 0) {
      bar.removeClass("barShowY");
    }
  }
  console.log(selection + " selected images");

});
```

```css
#bar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.show {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.delete {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar" class="hide">delete selected images?</div>

<div class="delete">delete</div>
<img src="https://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/UP2131/CUSA01736_00/Ll2fJdBTPQylZO0Z4JQ9rtsIJsojwBxn.png" alt="">

<div class="delete">delete</div>
<img src="https://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/UP2131/CUSA01736_00/lYG2Mgzz878Z8rU3yvlx9MwmR5dhDsyy.png" alt="">

<div class="delete">delete</div>
<img src="https://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/UP2131/CUSA01736_00/Zp2VXCJxT764bqDPyyIy0Yf2ZRFHzr3g.png" alt="">
```

Comment: your adding and removing classes logic needs some re-thinking. Bar always has class hide

Comment: Try using `var selection = $(selected).length;`

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Comment: you were right charlietfl, this is the working js bit:

Comment: var bar = $('#bar');
 var deleteBtn = $('.delete');

 
 deleteBtn.click(function(){  
  
  if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
   $(this).removeClass("selected");
  }else{
   $(this).addClass("selected");
  }
  
  var selection = $('.selected').length;
  
  if(bar.hasClass("hide")){   
   bar.addClass("show");
   bar.removeClass('hide');
  } else {
   if(selection==0){
    bar.removeClass("show");
    bar.addClass("hide");
   }     
  }
  
 });

Comment: why vote this down? how is this not a valid question?

Comment: Shouldn't you actually gather information of which image will be deleted? There is no actual code for that in your question. I mean in this snippet you only count clicks or better yet you count how many delete buttons have class `selected`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use :

```
 var selection = $('.selected').length;
```

Instead of :

```
var selection = selected.length;
```

Since the expression `var selected = $('.selected');` will save all the elements with selected class in `selection` variable when there's no elements with this class, that why it'll remain with count zero.

```js
var bar = $('#bar');
var deleteBtn = $('.delete');
var selection = 0;

deleteBtn.click(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  }

  var selection = $('.selected').length;

  if (bar.hasClass("hide")) {
    bar.addClass("show");
  } else {
    if (selection === 0) {
      bar.removeClass("barShowY");
    }
  }
  console.log(selection + " selected images");

});
```

```css
#bar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.show {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.delete {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar" class="hide">delete selected images?</div>

<div class="delete">delete</div>
<img src="https://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/UP2131/CUSA01736_00/Ll2fJdBTPQylZO0Z4JQ9rtsIJsojwBxn.png" alt="">

<div class="delete">delete</div>
<img src="https://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/UP2131/CUSA01736_00/lYG2Mgzz878Z8rU3yvlx9MwmR5dhDsyy.png" alt="">

<div class="delete">delete</div>
<img src="https://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/UP2131/CUSA01736_00/Zp2VXCJxT764bqDPyyIy0Yf2ZRFHzr3g.png" alt="">
```

Comment: you should remove the initialization of the `var selected = $('.selected');` from outside the delete function to inside or remove it totally.

Comment: We don't need it at all @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: yeah we dont need it.

Comment: thanks a lot Zakaria Acharki, as charlietfl pointed out, there was also a little problem with the hide/show logic, this is the final js, so all the above mentioned funcitonality works perfectly:

Comment: var bar = $('#bar');
 var deleteBtn = $('.delete');

 
 deleteBtn.click(function(){  
  
  if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
   $(this).removeClass("selected");
  }else{
   $(this).addClass("selected");
  }
  
  var selection = $('.selected').length;
  
  if(bar.hasClass("hide")){   
   bar.addClass("show");
   bar.removeClass('hide');
  } else {
   if(selection==0){
    bar.removeClass("show");
    bar.addClass("hide");
   }     
  }  
  console.log(selection + " selected images");
  
 });

Comment: My understanding that OP wanted the count of all selected images **AND** for the bar to be hidden if none were selected. Based on these requirements, how is this marked as correct?

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting the `.selected` class before applying the class on the element that is the main cause of error, move it inside the delete button see below

```js
var bar = $('#bar');
var deleteBtn = $('.delete');

var selection = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  deleteBtn.on('click', function() {
    console.log($('.selected').length);
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
      $(this).removeClass("selected");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    }

    var selection = $('.selected').length;

    if (bar.hasClass("hide")) {
      bar.addClass("show");
    } else {
      if (selection === 0) {
        bar.removeClass("barShowY");
      }
    }
    console.log(selection + " selected images");

  });
})
```

```css
#bar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.show {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.delete {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar" class="hide">delete selected images?</div>

<div class="delete">delete</div>
<img src="https://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/UP2131/CUSA01736_00/Ll2fJdBTPQylZO0Z4JQ9rtsIJsojwBxn.png" alt="">

<div class="delete">delete</div>
<img src="https://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/UP2131/CUSA01736_00/lYG2Mgzz878Z8rU3yvlx9MwmR5dhDsyy.png" alt="">

<div class="delete">delete</div>
<img src="https://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/UP2131/CUSA01736_00/Zp2VXCJxT764bqDPyyIy0Yf2ZRFHzr3g.png" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the following and I seem to be getting the results you're expecting

```
var selection = $('.selected').length;
if (bar.hasClass("hide")) {
  bar.removeClass("hide");
  bar.addClass("show");
} else {

  if (selection === 0) {
     bar.removeClass("show");
     bar.addClass("hide");
  }
}
```

Was `barShowY` supposed to be just `show`?

Codepen here : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dZQNxM

Comment: The hide/show logic was also an issue, not just the counter. This was to address the hide/show. Try it out in codepen.

Answer (score 0):

`selected` should be declared in the event handler. This should be your JS file:

```
var bar = $('#bar');
var deleteBtn = $('.delete');
var selection = 0;

deleteBtn.click(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  }

  var selected = $('.selected'); // Note these two lines
  var selection = selected.length;

  if (bar.hasClass("hide")) {
    bar.addClass("show");
  } else {
    if (selection === 0) {
      bar.removeClass("barShowY");
    }
  }

  console.log(selection + " selected images");
});
```

Check it out in CodePen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPMNeX?editors=1111
or on JSBin http://jsbin.com/cifekojasu/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Your collecting the amount of selected images when the document first loads. Therefore you'll always get the same number (0) due to caching. You'll have to recapture the amount on every click so it can live update.

```js
var bar = $('#bar');
var deleteBtn = $('.delete');

deleteBtn.click(function() {
  var selected;
  
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  
  selected = $('.selected').length;
  
  if (!selected) {
    bar.removeClass('show');
  } else {
    bar.addClass('show');
  }

  console.log($('.selected').length + " selected images");
});
```

```css
#bar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.show {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.delete {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar" class="hide">delete selected images?</div>

<div class="delete">delete</div>
<img src="https://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/UP2131/CUSA01736_00/Ll2fJdBTPQylZO0Z4JQ9rtsIJsojwBxn.png" alt="">

<div class="delete">delete</div>
<img src="https://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/UP2131/CUSA01736_00/lYG2Mgzz878Z8rU3yvlx9MwmR5dhDsyy.png" alt="">

<div class="delete">delete</div>
<img src="https://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/UP2131/CUSA01736_00/Zp2VXCJxT764bqDPyyIy0Yf2ZRFHzr3g.png" alt="">
```